# global $product is empty string when passed into function

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, variables, globals

I'm trying to optimize my functions.php file as I have a Woocommerce site with a bunch of customizations to the theme. Currently, my functions look like the following:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'enqueue_product_modals');
function enqueue_product_modals() {
    global $product;  //Accessing the Global
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    if (is_product()) {
        //Standard Modal:
        require_once 'modal-product.php';

        if (has_term('guitar-pickups', 'product_cat', $product_id)) {
            include_once 'modal-polarity.php';
        };

        if (has_term('mini-humbuckers', 'product_cat', $product_id)) {
            include_once 'modal-minihum.php';
        };
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', function () {
    global $product; //Accessing the Global Again
    $name = $product->get_name();
    if (have_comments()) {
        echo '<p class="reviews-tagline">Trying to leave a review for our ' . $name . '? <a class="expand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#review_form_wrapper" >Leave one here.</a></p>';
    }
}, 50);

etc.
```

I understand accessing the `global $product` multiple times is bad practice. So, I started to rewrite functions by declaring the `global $product` at the top of my functions.php file, (like I would in JS) and passing it in to each individual function like so:

```
global $product;

add_action('wp_footer', 'enqueue_product_modals');
function enqueue_product_modals($product) {
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    if (is_product()) {
       // code here...
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', function ($product) {

    $name = $product->get_name();
    if (have_comments()) {
       //code here
}, 50);
```

The problem is that now all functions are broken and when doing a `var_dump($product)` inside each function $product is an empty string. I am now positive I don't know what I'm doing. Can someone offer any assistance on the correct way to access the $product global in each function...or a better way?

---

## Edit:

I also tried passing the `$post` object, so rewriting the function like so, but it's still an empty string:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'enqueue_product_modals');
function enqueue_product_modals($post) {

    if (is_product()) {

$product = wc_get_product($post->ID); // hoping to use this
        var_dump($post); //Still empty String

    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t see anything wrong with what you were doing originally.

Comment: I was under the assumption and have read that using global multiple times is a bad practice and can slow down code. Is this incorrect?

Comment: The global is there for exactly this reason. Using it to add features and extending on the existing code is what it is designed to do :)

Comment: Is there a way to pass it as an argument to clean the code up?

Comment: You're overthinking it.  There's nothing wrong with your original code.  You were using the global the way it's intended to be used.   The reason it's empty when you access it the other way is because it does not exist as a global inside your function (because you didn't declare it as a global variable).  It's just a new variable for that function, and therefore empty.  If you want to access the global variable, you have to declare it as global INSIDE your function.

Comment: Okay awesome, thanks for letting me know I was confused reading about globals.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue here is that the calling context of hooks (eg. targets of add_action) are not the same as the functions.php inline code. Also, function parameters come from the calling context, not just because there is a variable of that name in the same file.

This "function enqueue_product_modals($product) " will not work.

As for use of Woo globals, I believe all of them are deprecated.
Here is how global $product gets set:

```
includes/wc-template-functions.php:140: unset( $GLOBALS['product'] );
includes/wc-template-functions.php:150: $GLOBALS['product'] = wc_get_product( $post );
includes/wc-template-functions.php:152: return $GLOBALS['product'];
```

So, you can see the "going forward" way to get the WC_Product object for a given post.

Comment: "This "function enqueue_product_modals($product) " will not work." - yes, that was the failed attempt to avoid using global $product everywhere though, and OP said it didn't work.

Comment: I don't know WC: so you're saying the right way to get a product nowadays is wc_get_product()?

Answer (score 0):

> So, I started to rewrite functions by declaring the global $product at the top of my functions.php file,

This is why it stopped working, because the `global` statement has to be inside the same scope as where you use it inside the function.

Using `global $product;` lots of times isn't bad because it's done lots of times, it's bad because using global variables is a code smell. The actual statement of `global $product;` doesn't reduce performance in any meaningful way.

**Note that this isn't a WooCommerce thing, or even a WordPress thing, it's a general PHP thing.**

Instead, you should be using the APIs provided by the plugin to retrieve the current product, not the global variables.

The comments left already imply that this is how you would do it, but you should ask in a WooCommerce community if that's the case as questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here:

```php
$product = wc_get_product();
```